# Can "shout" or "scream" be used to introduce reported speech?

Tags: reported-speech

Is it grammatically correct to say:

> She shouted at him that he hooked up with his friend.

> She screams at him that he is stupid.

Comment: What makes you doubt either of them?

Comment: I am unsure because in German "scream" and "shout" can't be used that way.

Comment: Any substitute for _said_ can be used with either direct or reported speech.

Comment: There is no reported speech there at all.

Comment: @paul Are you sure.  I [found](https://eisundfeuer.fandom.com/de/wiki/A_Storm_of_Swords_-_Kapitel_34_-_Arya_VI) *Sie schreit ihn an, dass er zur Hölle fahren soll, aber eine Stimme hinter ihr sagt, dass er schon in der Hölle sei.* and many other similar examples